# Is it possible to achieve update or delete functionality with POST and without using hidden() in the view

Tags: php, html, laravel, http

Good day to all, I am new to Laravel framework and as I read some articles about HTTP verbs which say that POST is universal to both PUT and DELETE (reference:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

) and thus I wonder if it is possible to achieve Update and Delete functionality with POST and without using hidden() in the view itself. For example, if you look at the code below hidden method is used to clarify which HTTP verb should be used in this case PUT and what if I remove it and try to update the data will it be possible.
The code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Income</h1>
<br>
{!! Form::open(['action'=>['IncomeController@update',$income->id], 'method' =>'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('Title', 'Title')}}
    {{Form::text('Title', $income->Title, ['class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder' =>'Enter title'])}}

    </div>
    **{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}**
    {{Form::submit('Create', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Comment: yes, it will be possible to use `POST` for `PUT` and `DELETE` but then you need to define the Route for put and delete task with POST type

Comment: @rkj, Please can you create solution to my question and show how exactly it is possible, with codes. Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose if you have Route like this

```
Route::put('income/update/{id}', 'IncomeController@update');
Route::delete('income/delete/{id}', 'IncomeController@delete');
```

Then you can replace your route with this

```
Route::post('income/update/{id}', 'IncomeController@update');
Route::post('income/delete/{id}', 'IncomeController@delete');
```

And then change your form like this (Just remove the `hidden` field)

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>Income</h1>
<br>
{!! Form::open(['action'=>['IncomeController@update',$income->id], 'method' =>'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('Title', 'Title')}}
    {{Form::text('Title', $income->Title, ['class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder' =>'Enter title'])}}

    </div>
    {{Form::submit('Create', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Comment: Great, one more thing can you please explain as an expert which way is better to achieve UPDATE and DELETE functionality with hidden() or routes and why.thank you in advance

Comment: Come on dude I know noone likes explaining but I had to ask this question since it is important for me :)

Comment: @Mirich you can use any one, but when you specify `PUT` or `DELETE` in your Route then it looks specific for update and delete however `POST` route looks like  creating